Cycling thru themes and and using composer with PyQGIS
I'm trying to make QGIS go through a few themes and export the map with the Composer but I don't manage to switch theme.
I tried to get some help from ChatGPT and I few snippets I found on GitHub, looks there's been some change lately in the way PyQGIS can apply themes but without any luck.
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsLayoutExporter
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QDateTime

project = QgsProject.instance()
layout_manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = layout_manager.layoutByName("Zoom")

if not layout:
    print("Erreur : Le layout 'Zoom' n'existe pas.")
else:

    # themes
    themes = ["th1", "th2"]

    available_themes = project.mapThemeCollection().mapThemes()

    for theme in themes:
        if theme not in available_themes:
            print(f"Erreur : Le thème '{theme}' n'existe pas.")
            continue

        project.mapThemeCollection().setCurrentTheme(theme)
        print(f"Thème '{theme}' appliqué.")
        
        exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
        output_path = f"/Users/XXX/Downloads/{theme}_layout_{QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('yyyyMMdd_hhmmss')}.pdf"

        export_settings = QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()
        result = exporter.exportToPdf(output_path, export_settings)

        if result == QgsLayoutExporter.Success:
            print(f"Exportation du thème '{theme}' réussie : {output_path}")
        else:
            print(f"Erreur lors de l'exportation du thème '{theme}'.")


I get this error
File "Sans titre 0", line 22, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsMapThemeCollection' object has no attribute 'setCurrentTheme'

Any ideas about fixing this ?

The first thing to do would be consult the documentation for QgsMapThemeCollection. Indeed, there is no method setCurrentTheme().
There is a method applyTheme() which will:

Apply theme given by its name and modify layer tree, current style of
layers and checked legend items of passed layer tree model.

This method also takes QgsLayerTreeGroup and QgsLayerTreeModel objects so you need to retrieve those and pass them to the applyTheme() method.
Try the modified code below:
project = QgsProject.instance()

# Retrieve the layer tree root and layer tree model
lt_model = iface.layerTreeView().layerTreeModel()
lt_root = lt_model.rootGroup()

layout_manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = layout_manager.layoutByName("Zoom")

if not layout:
    print("Erreur : Le layout 'Zoom' n'existe pas.")
else:

    # themes
    themes = ["th1", "th2"]

    available_themes = project.mapThemeCollection().mapThemes()

    for theme in themes:
        if theme not in available_themes:
            print(f"Erreur : Le thème '{theme}' n'existe pas.")
            continue
        
        # Apply the map theme
        project.mapThemeCollection().applyTheme(theme, lt_root, lt_model)
        print(f"Thème '{theme}' appliqué.")
        
        exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
        output_path = f"C:\\Users\\XXX\\Downloads\\{theme}_layout_{QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('yyyyMMdd_hhmmss')}.pdf"

        export_settings = QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()
        result = exporter.exportToPdf(output_path, export_settings)

        if result == QgsLayoutExporter.Success:
            print(f"Exportation du thème '{theme}' réussie : {output_path}")
        else:
            print(f"Erreur lors de l'exportation du thème '{theme}'.")

